# How to trigger ADF pipeline just on Weekdays?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, pipeline

I have an ADF pipeline which need to run every 4 hours in Central European Time zone.

I figured out how to set the trigger to run the pipeline.

But, I don't know to make it run just on Weekdays?

I don't want to run the pipeline on Weekends.

How to make it run every 4 hours just from Mondays thru Fridays?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the recurrence to every 1 week and then set the days and hours you want the pipeline to run.

[image]

Comment: Awesome.... Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can schedule a Trigger on Weekdays:

**Step 1:** After you set the Time zone. in the recurence drop down Set every 1 and set it Week(s).

[image]

**Step 2:** Once set the recurence to Week(s) in the advanced recurence options you can select the day(s) you wanna run.

**Step 3:** As you mentioned you want to schedule the trigger for every 4 Hour(s) you can mention the timings that you want to Run the trigger.

[image]

***Note: Make sure to "Publish" for trigger to be activated after clicking "OK"***

Comment: Awesome.. I can only accept one answer.. so I just accepted the answer which based on time. Both answers are equally good.